# How to display history from UITextField using UILabels?

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, nsuserdefaults

So I have 3 `UITextFields` in one view of my application and 5 labels in another view. The purpose of the app is for the user to input up to three lines of text and then make it do some cool animated stuff. What I'm trying to do is record/display the 5 most recent entries that the user has made in my view with the labels. In other words, I'd like to show 5 previous things that the user has put into the app using the textfields.

I would like to display the text in each label using the format (string for textfield1, string for 2, string for 3). I was thinking about using `NSUserDefaults` to accomplish this. If you could point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it, thank you! Also, if you need me to clarify just let me know.

Here's what I'm doing now...

```
- (IBAction)dismissUserInputPage {
    link4 = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(moveTextInputDown)];
    [link4 addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
    [link3 invalidate];

    userInputButton2.hidden = YES;
    userInputButton1.hidden = NO;

    NSString *line1 = textField1.text;
    NSString *line2 = textField2.text;
    NSString *line3 = textField3.text;

    NSUserDefaults *line1Text = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [line1Text setObject:line1 forKey:@"line1Text"];

    NSUserDefaults *line2Text = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [line2Text setObject:line2 forKey:@"line2Text"];

    NSUserDefaults *line3Text = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [line3Text setObject:line3 forKey:@"line3Text"];
}

- (IBAction)presentHistoryView {
    historyView.hidden = NO;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    historyView.alpha = 1.0;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    historyButton1.hidden = YES;
    historyButton2.hidden = NO;

    NSUserDefaults *line1Text = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *tempString1 = [line1Text stringForKey:@"line1Text"];

    NSUserDefaults *line2Text = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *tempString2 = [line2Text stringForKey:@"line2Text"];

    NSUserDefaults *line3Text = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *tempString3 = [line3Text stringForKey:@"line3Text"];

    historyLabel1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@, %@", tempString1, tempString2, tempString3];
}
```

The problem with this is that I don't know how to then move the first entry down to another label when the user inputs more text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store an array of dictionaries with the key value pair being the text you want to store and an NSDate.  Then you can sort the array by date time and pick of the latest n you need.